# Creating new conditioned factor variable from multiple binary variables in R

Tags: r

I need to make a new 3-level categorical variable that reflects whether a subject died of a certain class of drug in an overdose. The levels would be something like: "Class A only", "Class B only", "Class A + Class B".

Within the data frame, there are numerous (about 90) different individual drugs variables that are binary variables (0/1) which indicate if that drug was found in the subject's toxicology. What I would need to do is find a way to create this new factor variable that would tell us if one of the, say 25, drugs that are of Class A were found in that individual subject and then assign the new factor variable a value of "Class A" or "Class A + Class B" depending if a Class B drug was also present.

I'm overwhelmed with where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried. Also you should send an example database/dataset for others to better comprehend what you are saying. Please also try to include, an expected output. It is easier for others to answer questions then.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, I can explain to you the steps that may work. Since you are overwhelmed with where to start, this should hopefully give you a framework on how to think about solving problems like this.

1) First, we need to know what drugs are of class A and class B. Assuming you have this information, you can separate the two classes into their own data frames (keep the original still)

2) Next, we need to know if a subject contained a drug. We can do so by creating a new column on each data frame that TRUE or FALSE. The condition we will check is if the sum of the row is greater than 0. If true, then at least one drug must have had a value of 1. For example:

```
df.class.A$has.drug <- ifelse(rowSums(df.class.A > 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

3) We need to now make a column in the original data frame by checking three conditions.

```
df$drugs <- ifelse(df.class.A$has.drug == TRUE, 
                   ifelse(df.class.B$has.drug == TRUE, 'Class A and B', 'Class A'), 
                   ifelse(df.class.B$has.drug == TRUE, 'Class B', 'NONE'))
```

The first ifelse says "if we have Class A, check if we have Class B, otherwise, check we if have class B".

The second ifelse says "We have Class A, so if we have class B then put "class A nd B", if we don't have class B then just put "Class A".

The last one says "We do not have Class A, so if we have class B then just put "Class B", if we don't have class B then we have nothing, so put "none" (you could also put NA or anything else).